# VS Code Dart Extension: Stuck at "Searching for projects..." after Mac Sonoma upgrade

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

After the Mac OS Sonoma upgrade, the VS Code Dart extension is stuck at “searching for projects...”. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Dart and Flutter extensions, restarting VS Code, and rebooting. No success. I can't run/debug my Flutter app in this state. Any ideas?

VS Code 1.82.2
Flutter v3.72.0
Dart v3.72.2

[image]

Comment: I don't see any related issue tickets. I suggest that you [raise one](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/new/choose). Once you do, please add a link here to your issue ticket so I can follow it.